# Web Forms For Marketers: Custom Field/Action accessing the rendering's parameters?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I may be approaching this from completely the wrong angle, but would greatly appreciate some direction.

I have a WFFM form that needs to go on many pages. It will have the exact same fields for every page. However, it needs to have a different "to" email address per location. I've done a lot of research/thinking, and I think the best approach might be to set the email address as a parameter in the form rendering. However, I'm having trouble accessing the parameter from the control/action.

I'm able to access it from the control by doing Parent.Parent.Parent... etc, but obviously that's a really fragile solution. Surely there's a better approach than this?